# ajax with javascript(jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

i have used validation using javascript(jquery) and then i apply that validation to asp.net controls in ajax update panel.Although the validations works fine but the problem is that the event of button control is not being blocked, so the validation occurs correctly but still the button event code is executed..which i dont want,n e help ??
the code described below :-

```
<head>
<link href="css/template.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><br/>
<link href="css/validationEngine.jquery.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><br/>
<script src="js/jquery-1.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><br/>
<script src="js/jquery.validationEngine-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script><br/>
<script src="js/jquery.validationEngine.js" type="text/javascript"></script><br/>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("#form1").validationEngine();
});
</script>;
</head>
<body style="background-color:White">
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <div style="float:right;margin-top:250px;margin-right:550px;overflow:visible;position:relative">     
     <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server">
        <ProgressTemplate>
            <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/updt1.gif" />
        </ProgressTemplate>

     </asp:UpdateProgress>


        </div>
        <div style="position:absolute;background-color:White">
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
<div align="left" style="position:fixed;float:left;height:100%;width:200px;border-bottom:5px solid Black;border-right:5px solid Black;border-left:5px solid Black;border-top:5px solid Black; background-color: Green">
    <asp:Label ID="lblacc" runat="server" Text="My Account" Font-Bold="True" 
        Font-Size="Large"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <hr style="background-color:Gray;height:5px" />
    <div align="right">
    <asp:SiteMapPath ID="SiteMapPath1" runat="server" Font-Size="Large">
    </asp:SiteMapPath>
    <hr style="background-color:Gray;height:5px" />
    <table style="text-align:right;font-size:large;color:Black"> 
    <tr><td><asp:LinkButton ID="lnk1" runat="server" ForeColor="White" onclick="lnk1_Click">General</asp:LinkButton></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td><asp:LinkButton ID="lnk2" runat="server" ForeColor="White" onclick="lnk2_Click">Edit Profile</asp:LinkButton></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td><asp:LinkButton ID="lnk3" runat="server" ForeColor="White" 
            onclick="lnk3_Click">Change Password</asp:LinkButton></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td><asp:LinkButton ID="lnk4" runat="server" ForeColor="White" 
            onclick="lnk4_Click">Connection</asp:LinkButton></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td><asp:LinkButton ID="lnk5" runat="server" ForeColor="White" 
            onclick="lnk5_Click">Complaint</asp:LinkButton></td></tr>
    <tr><td>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk6" runat="server" ForeColor="White" 
        onclick="lnk6_Click">Logout</asp:LinkButton></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
     </table>
    </div>
</div>

<div style="background-color:White;color: #0000FF;width:83%;height:auto;margin-left:212px;position:absolute">
   <asp:MultiView ID="mvuser" runat="server" ActiveViewIndex="0">
        <asp:View ID="vgenp" runat="server">
        <div style="float:left">
        <div style="float:left;width:100%">
        <h4 align="left">General Profile</h4>
        <hr />
        <table align="left" style="text-align:right">
        <tr><td rowspan="7" style="width:100px;height:100px">
            <asp:Image ID="imgdefpro" runat="server" ImageUrl="" Width="300px" Height="300px"/>
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td rowspan="6"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="First Name :"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
        <asp:Label ID="lblfnm" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>
            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Last Name :"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
        <asp:Label ID="lbllnm" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>
            <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="User Name :"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
        <asp:Label ID="lblunm" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>
            <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text="Age :"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
        <asp:Label ID="lblage" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>
            <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text="Join Date :"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
        <asp:Label ID="lbldoj" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <br /><br />
        </div>

        <div style="float:left;width:100%">
        <br /><br />
         <h4 align="left">Contact</h4>
         <hr />
         <br />
        <table align="left" style="text-align:right">
        <tr><td>
            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Email :"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
        <asp:Label ID="lblemail" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>
            <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="Mobile :"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
        <asp:Label ID="lblmob" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <br /><br />
        </div>
        <div style="float:left;width:100%">
        <br /><br />
        <h4 align="left">Address</h4>
        <hr />
        <table align="left" style="text-align:right">
        <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text="Location :"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtloc" runat="server" ReadOnly="True" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" Text="Pincode :"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lblpin" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" Text="City :"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lblcity" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <br /><br />
        </div>
        </div>
        </asp:View>
        <asp:View ID="veditp" runat="server">
        <div style="float:left">
        <div style="float:left">
        <table align="left" style="text-align:right">
        <tr><td colspan="2">
            <asp:Image ID="imgpropic" Width="300px" Height="300px" runat="server"/>
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td align="left">
            <asp:FileUpload ID="fupropic" runat="server" />
        </td>
        <td rowspan="3" valign="bottom">
        <asp:Button ID="btnimgcncl" runat="server" Text="Cancel" 
                onclick="btnimgcncl_Click" />
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td align="left">
            <asp:Button ID="btnimgtry" runat="server" Text="Try it!" 
                onclick="btnimgtry_Click" /><br />
                <asp:Label ID="lblerr" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Text="" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                </td></tr>
        <tr><td align="left">
            <asp:Button ID="btnimgsave" runat="server" Text="Save" 
                onclick="btnimgsave_Click" />
        </td></tr>
        </table>
        </div>
        <div style="float:left;width:100%">
        <br /><br />
        <h4 align="left">General Profile</h4>
        <hr />
        <table align="left" style="text-align:right">
        <tr><td rowspan="6" style="width:100px;height:100px">
            &nbsp;</td></tr>
        <tr><td rowspan="5"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>
            <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="First Name :"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtfnm" runat="server" CssClass="validate[required]"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>
            <asp:Label ID="Label12" runat="server" Text="Last Name :"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
         <asp:TextBox ID="txtlnm" runat="server" CssClass="validate[required]"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>
            <asp:Label ID="Label14" runat="server" Text="User Name :"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
         <asp:TextBox ID="txtunm" runat="server" CssClass="validate[required]" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>
            <asp:Label ID="Label16" runat="server" Text="Age :"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtage" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <br /><br />
        </div>
        <div style="float:left;width:100%">
        <br /><br />
         <h4 align="left">Contact</h4>
         <hr />
         <br />
        <table align="left" style="text-align:right">
        <tr><td>
            <asp:Label ID="Label18" runat="server" Text="Email :"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
         <asp:TextBox ID="txtemail" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>
            <asp:Label ID="Label20" runat="server" Text="Mobile :"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
         <asp:TextBox ID="txtmob" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
        <br /><br />
        <div style="float:left;width:100%">
        <br /><br />
        <h4 align="left">Address</h4>
        <hr />
        <table align="left" style="text-align:right">
        <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="Label22" runat="server" Text="Location :"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtloc2" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="Label23" runat="server" Text="Pincode :"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
             <asp:TextBox ID="txtpin" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="Label25" runat="server" Text="City :"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddluserct" runat="server">
            </asp:DropDownList>            
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td></td></tr>
        </table>
        <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
        </div>

        <div align="center" style="float:left;width:100%">    
        <table>
        <tr><td>
            <asp:Button ID="btnupdt" runat="server" Text="Update" CssClass="styled-button-1" onclick="btnupdt_Click" /></td><td></td>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="btncncl" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CssClass="styled-button-1" onclick="btncncl_Click" /></td></tr>
        </table>
        <br /><br />
        </div>
        </div>
        </asp:View>
        <asp:View ID="vchngpass" runat="server">
        <table align="left" style="width:350px">
        <tr><td>Enter Your Old Password :</td><td><asp:TextBox ID="txtoldpass" runat="server" AutoComplete="off"></asp:TextBox></td></tr>
        <tr><td>
            <asp:Button ID="btnverify" runat="server" Text="Verify" 
                onclick="btnverify_Click" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td>
            <asp:Label ID="lbloldpass" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></td></tr>
        </table>
        <div>
            <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Visible="false">

        <table align="left" style="width:350px;margin-top:-55px;margin-left:400px">
        <tr><td>
            <asp:Label ID="lblnwpass" runat="server" Text="Enter New Password :"></asp:Label></td><td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtnewpass" runat="server" AutoComplete="off" ></asp:TextBox></td></tr>
        <tr><td>
            <asp:Label ID="lblnwpass2" runat="server" Text="Re-Enter New Password :"></asp:Label></td><td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtcnfmpass" runat="server" AutoComplete="off"></asp:TextBox></td></tr>
         <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="btnsvpass" runat="server" Text="Save" 
                    onclick="btnsvpass_Click" /></td>
         </tr>
         <tr><td>
             <asp:Label ID="lblsvpass" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></td></tr>
        </table>
        </asp:Panel>
        </div> 
        </asp:View>
        <asp:View ID="vcon" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
                onpageindexchanging="FormView1_PageIndexChanging" DataKeyNames="con_ono" Width="500px">
            <ItemTemplate>
            <div align="left" style="text-align:right">
            <table>
            <tr><th>Connection Details : -<br /><br /></th></tr>
            <tr><td></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Application Date :</td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="Label13" runat="server" Text='<%# bind("con_date") %>'></asp:Label></td>
            <tr><td>Type :</td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lbltype" runat="server" Text='<%# bind("con_type") %>'></asp:Label></td>
            <tr><td>Purpose :</td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblpur" runat="server" Text='<%# bind("con_purpose") %>'></asp:Label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td>Address :</td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtadd" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" ReadOnly="true" Text='<%# bind("con_add") %>'></asp:TextBox></td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td>Area :</td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblarea" runat="server" Text='<%# bind("con_area") %>'></asp:Label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td>Pin :</td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblpin" runat="server" Text='<%# bind("con_pin") %>'></asp:Label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td rowspan="3">Contact :</td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td>Home : <asp:Label ID="lblhome" runat="server" Text='<%# bind("con_home") %>'></asp:Label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td>Mobile : <asp:Label ID="lblmob" runat="server" Text='<%# bind("con_mobile") %>'></asp:Label></td>

            </tr>
            <tr><td>No Of Flores :</td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblflores" runat="server" Text='<%# bind("con_flore") %>'></asp:Label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td>Area In Sqm :</td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblsqm" runat="server" Text='<%# bind("con_area_sq") %>'></asp:Label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td>Order No. :</td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblono" runat="server" Text='<%# bind("con_ono") %>'></asp:Label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td>Status :</td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblstatus" runat="server" Text='<%# bind("con_status") %>'></asp:Label></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            </div> <%--Div ends here--%>
           <br /><br /><br />
            <div align="right" style="text-align:right">
            <table>
            <tr><th>Applicant's Details : -<br /><br /></th></tr>
            <tr><td></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Address :</td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtappadd" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" ReadOnly="true" Text='<%# bind("app_add") %>'></asp:TextBox></td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td></td></tr>
            <tr><td>City :</td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblappct" runat="server" Text='<%# bind("cityname") %>'></asp:Label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Email :</td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblappeml" runat="server" Text='<%# bind("app_email") %>'></asp:Label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td></td></tr>
             <tr><td rowspan="3">Contact :</td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td>Home : <asp:Label ID="lblapphm" runat="server" Text='<%# bind("app_home") %>'></asp:Label></td>
            </tr>

            <tr><td>Mobile : <asp:Label ID="lblappmob" runat="server" Text='<%# bind("app_mobile") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            </div> <%--Div ends here--%>
            </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:FormView>
                <br />
            <div align="left"><asp:Button ID="btnpdfcon" CssClass="styled-button-1" 
                    runat="server" Text="Download Pdf" onclick="btnpdfcon_Click" />
            </div><br /><br />
            </div>
        </asp:View>
        <asp:View ID="vcmp" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:FormView ID="FormView2" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
                onpageindexchanging="FormView2_PageIndexChanging" DataKeyNames="cmp_ono" Width="500px">
            <ItemTemplate>
            <div align="left" style="text-align:right">
            <table>
            <tr><th>Complaint Details : -<br /><br /></th></tr>
            <tr><td></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Application Date :</td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="Label13" runat="server" Text='<%# bind("cmp_date") %>'></asp:Label></td>
            <tr><td>Category :</td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblcat" runat="server" Text='<%# bind("cmp_cat") %>'></asp:Label></td>
            <tr><td>Description :</td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lbldes" runat="server" Text='<%# bind("cmp_des") %>'></asp:Label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td>Address :</td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtadd" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" ReadOnly="true" Text='<%# bind("cmp_add") %>'></asp:TextBox></td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td>Area :</td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblarea" runat="server" Text='<%# bind("cmp_area") %>'></asp:Label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td>Pin :</td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblpin" runat="server" Text='<%# bind("cmp_pin") %>'></asp:Label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td rowspan="3">Contact :</td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td>Home : <asp:Label ID="lblhome" runat="server" Text='<%# bind("cmp_home") %>'></asp:Label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td>Mobile : <asp:Label ID="lblmob" runat="server" Text='<%# bind("cmp_mobile") %>'></asp:Label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td>Order No. :</td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblono" runat="server" Text='<%# bind("cmp_ono") %>'></asp:Label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td>Status :</td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblstatus" runat="server" Text='<%# bind("cmp_status") %>'></asp:Label></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            </div> <%--Div ends here--%>
           <br /><br /><br />
            <div align="right" style="text-align:right">
            <table>
            <tr><th>Applicant's Details : -<br /><br /></th></tr>
            <tr><td></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Address :</td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtappadd" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" ReadOnly="true" Text='<%# bind("app_add") %>'></asp:TextBox></td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td></td></tr>
            <tr><td>City :</td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblappct" runat="server" Text='<%# bind("cityname") %>'></asp:Label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Email :</td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblappeml" runat="server" Text='<%# bind("app_email") %>'></asp:Label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td></td></tr>
             <tr><td rowspan="3">Contact :</td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td>Home : <asp:Label ID="lblapphm" runat="server" Text='<%# bind("app_home") %>'></asp:Label></td>
            </tr>

            <tr><td>Mobile : <asp:Label ID="lblappmob" runat="server" Text='<%# bind("app_mobile") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            </div> <%--Div ends here--%>

            </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:FormView>
            <br />
            <div align="left">
             <asp:Button ID="btnpdfcmp" CssClass="styled-button-1" runat="server" 
                    Text="Download Pdf" onclick="btnpdfcmp_Click"/></div>
            <br />
            <br /></div>
        </asp:View>
    </asp:MultiView>
    </div>
     </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: less code helps for more answers

Comment: Oh dear. I don't even want to look at this.

Answer (score 0):

Use following code Instead of your jquery code

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(PageLoaded);
});
function PageLoaded(sender, args) {
   //Your Validate code here
}
```